# Accelerating 3-dimensional lookup table in an array in C

Tags: arrays

I have a 3-dimensional lookup table LUT[WIDTH][HEIGHT][DEPTH]. I have to apply this LUT to each pixel in a large image (4k x 4k) and I need to improve the performance. I tried the approach below:

```
u8 lut[1024][1024][32];
u16 image[4096][4096];
u16 image2[4096][4096];

for (z = 0; z < 32; z++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 4096; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < 4096; x++) {
             ci1 = colorindex = image[x + y*4096]
             ci2 = colorindex2 = image2[x + y*4096]
             result_image[x + (y*4096) + (z*4096*4096)] = lut[ci + (1024*ci2) + (1024*1024)*z];
        }       
     }
```

But the results are not good. Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: The above loop alone will take roughly 500 million FLOPs.  What is the current running time, and what do you expect here?

Comment: 0 FLOPS. No floating point there.

Comment: Is there a better way to do lookup tables in C? I'm using an ARM SoC Cortex A8. Is there a way to take advantage of SIMD like NEON in C or with a library?